# Plot surface on Matlab using n Z-Coordinate Points and mxn (X & Y points)

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, surface

I have an issue where I have my data formatted such that I have n data points in the Z axis, and every Z data point has m corresponding x & y points. I essentially want to have n 2D m-point plots, but merged into one surface.

My data takes the following form:

```
z = [0 1 2 3]

data(:, :, 1) = [0 1 2; 2 2 2] (the first row corresponds to the x points, second to the y; the page (the 1) corresponds to the respective z point at which I am plotting said x and y points)
```

So essentially, at `z(i)`, I would like to have `data(:, :, i)` plotted. Then finally all merged together into one surface. How would I accomplish this?

An example that might help imagine the situation is if `data(:, :, i)` for all `i` was uniform, like the above sample, then a cube surface (of volume 12) would be drawn.

Comment: A little bit of code in-context would really help to clarify your question. Thanks!

Comment: If you can show some data and maybe an example image of what you're expecting the output to look like, that would also help.  I'm having trouble visualizing this

Answer (score 0):

> So essentially, at z(i), I would like to have data(:, :, i) plotted. Then finally all merged together into one surface. How would I accomplish this?

Use `scatter3` to plot [3-D scatter plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html), for every points with a set of x,y,z value.

Alternatively, use `plot3` to [make 3-D line plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html). Be careful with the argument formats.

You can use code like

```
for ii = 1:length(z)
    x = data(1, :, ii);
    y = data(2, :, ii);
    scatter3(x, y, z*ones(1, length(x));
end
```

Finally, [rotate your angle of view](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html) using `view([0,0,-1])` to the direction facing the z axis. By this, all layers of different z values are squeezed into one layer.

If you really mean you want to ignore the z-values, but only want to see an overlayed plot of all the points,

```
for ii = 1:length(z)
    x = data(1, :, ii);
    y = data(2, :, ii);
    scatter(x, y);
end
```

> An example that might help imagine the situation is if data(:, :, i) for all i was uniform, like the above sample, then a cube surface (of volume 12) would be drawn.

As @rayryeng commented, I found this difficult to imagine. What do you mean by "a cube surface of volume 12"? This part looks different than descriptions above it.